# Utterly lost importing functions for pytest

Tags: python, pytest

I know there are several pytest and importing questions and answers here but I'm not able to find a solution :(

PS After rereading import tutorials have changed my project folder structure a bit and edited the examples below.

My simple directory structure for a demo python project is as follows:

```
.
├── src
│   └── addsub
│       ├── __init__.py
│       └── addsub.py
└── tests
    ├── test_add.py
    └── test_subtract.py
```

src/addsub/addsub.py has the following content:

```
""" a demo module """

def add(a, b):
    """ sum two numbers or concat two strings """
    return a + b

def subtract(a: int, b:int) -> int:
    """ subtract b from a --- bugged for the demo """
    return a + b  

def main():
        print(f"Adding 3 to 4 makes: {add(3,4)}")
        print(f"Subtracting 4 from 3 makes: {subtract(3,4)}")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

while my test files are under the tests directory with test_add.py having the following content:

```
from src.addsub import add

def test_add():
    assert add(2, 3) == 5
    assert add('space', 'ship') == 'spaceship'
```

Now when I run pytest from the projects root directory I get the following errors:

```
====================================================== test session starts ======================================================
platform darwin -- Python 3.8.15, pytest-7.2.1, pluggy-1.0.0
rootdir: /Users/bob/Documents/work/code/ci-example
plugins: anyio-3.6.2
collected 0 items / 1 error                                                                                                     

============================================================ ERRORS =============================================================
______________________________________________ ERROR collecting tests/test_add.py _______________________________________________
ImportError while importing test module '/Users/bob/Documents/work/code/ci-example/tests/test_add.py'.
Hint: make sure your test modules/packages have valid Python names.
Traceback:
/Users/bob/opt/miniconda3/lib/python3.8/importlib/__init__.py:127: in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
tests/test_add.py:1: in <module>
    from src.addsub import add
E   ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'src'
==================================================== short test summary info ====================================================
ERROR tests/test_add.py
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! Interrupted: 1 error during collection !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
======================================================= 1 error in 0.06s ========================================================
```

Thanks in advance for any clarification.

Comment: I have projects with really similar folders structure, and I think `from src.mymodule import add` should work. Try to execute pytest with the command `pytest tests/`

Comment: Thanks for trying to help but no it does not work :(  changed the import in the test_add.py file to "from src.addsub import add" but and invoked pytest as you suggest but get "tests/test_add.py:1: in <module>
    from src.addsub import add
E   ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'src'"

Comment: with your new folder structure, it should be: `from src.addsub.addsub import add`

Comment: I am really sorry, must be doing something really dumb, but its not working :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`src` should not be an importable package (should not contain an __init__.py) but be a path where python can find importable packages.

The tooling you are using (pipenv, poetry, etc) can affect this or present an opinionated default behaviour, but the issue boils down to making sure path/to/your/project/src is in `sys.path` and just write `from addsub import add, subtract`.

A simple, vanilla way to fix this is

```
export PYTHONPATH=./src
```

using an absolute or relative path depending on your needs.

But either pipenv and poetry should do something that saves the day with that folder structure.

Comment: Thanks! As you can see in the updated directory tree ./src does not contain an init file. If I import sys and print sys.path in my addsub.py program I see "'/Users/bob/Documents/work/code/ci-example/src/addsub'" as the first argument. Setting an explicit PYTHONPATH does not work.

Comment: If you copied what I wrote, it wouldn't work because there was a typo. src/addsub should not be in the pythonpath unless your main script is in that folder or you start a shell from there

Comment: Thanks. No I had spotted the type and set PYTHONPATH correctly. Yes, I am starting pytest from the project's "root" directory